# Is there any javascript ssh client?

Tags: security, ssh, javascript, html5, socket

I mean pure javascript client that uses HTML5 sockets and doesn't need to be installed, just open single js file in browser. Is it possible to write such client at all?

Comment: @TomO'Connor Why?

Comment: This is why it scares the bejesus out of you: http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/  Even if it is possible to write an SSH client in Javascript, it is not possible to write a **secure** SSH client in javascript.

Comment: @Ladadadada From my reading of that article, a JS SSH client would be fine as long as it and the page it's on were delivered via SSL.

Comment: Even if the code is delivered over SSL, you can't generate or store keys securely in javascript so doing the crypto for SSH would be pointless.  Implementing telnet-over-ssl in javascript may be possible to do securely and may also be worthwhile if it solves Poma's problem.

Comment: no: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897649/is-it-possible-to-connect-to-ssh-using-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not pure HTML5, but there are other online (html/js/css based)

- [Firessh](http://lifehacker.com/5783594/firessh-is-a-browser-based-ssh-client-written-entirely-in-javascript)
- [<del>Webshell</del>](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mressl/webshell/) (no longer resolves as of 06/2016)
- [<del>sshterm</del>](http://sshterm.com/) (no longer resolves as of 06/2016)

Comment: Firessh is a Firefox plugin, which means it has access to true random numbers from your OS.  More secure than pure javascript can be but no good if you can't install plugins or aren't using Firefox.  Webshell involves installing a Python script on your server to accept the AJAX requests.  Very similar to GateOne in Bart's answer.  Must use SSL for encryption.  sshterm is a free ssl-to-ssh proxy.  All your passwords go through someone else's server where they are decrypted from the SSL and then used for the SSH connection to your server.  I would not recommend this option.

Answer (score 4):

Not in JavaScript that I know off, but you can run a python script on the server that will provide you with an ssh-shell in a browser.

[GateOne](https://github.com/liftoff/GateOne)

Comment: Same with shellinabox which is pre-packaged for debian/ubuntu. You then use any javascript enabled browser to connect to the server that runs the shellinabox daemon.

Answer (score 0):

Not javascript, but there's at least one [java ssh applet](http://javassh.org/space/start).

Comment: Has not been updated since 2005.